# Different Images in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, image

I have a question related to gridviews in ASP.NET

I have a gridview that I pull information from a SQL db and it displays the username and current status IE;

- Username  |  Status
- user1     |  Logged Out
- user2     |  Logged in
- user3     |  On Leave

So this is working all handy dandy, however what I'd like to do is rather that display text for status, I would like to display a "bullet type" image with different colors.  red, green, orange, blue - for different status.

Do I need to get these images into the db somehow, or can I use some sort of IF statement to just say, if the status is "1 - Logged in" then display "green.png"?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the corresponding CSS Class, and then set the CSS to use the fitting Background Image. I Think you cannot use a BoundField, but you have to use a TemplateField like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="StateBar State<%#eval("State") %>">&nbsp;</div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And then have a CSS like this:

```
.StateBar{
display:block;
width:10px;
height:10px;
}

.StateLoggedOut{
background-image:url(/images/...);
}
```

Hint: Try to have the Status Fields without " "

Comment: +1 We do similar things - doesn't have to be in CSS mind you - you could just have something like: <img src="/images/<%#eval("State") %>.png" alt="<%eval("State") %>" />

Comment: But css will keep it more maintainable. I would advise to use a span with text in it, and hide it using css to make it more accessible.

Comment: Look for Accessible Image Replacement to see how that's done.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 way of achieving this:

1 - Modify your query so that the image url comes directly in a column
2 - Do the image selection on the grid construction.

Either way you are going to have to create a template column with a image in it.

Do you need help with that?